# Unexpected error after migration to a new host

Tags: deployment

I'm having a bit of trouble finding out what's going on with my Drupal installation. I started building a site on a test server a while ago. Now it's time to move the entire website as it is to a new host. Therefore, all the database tables with content have been copied to a new database. Also the directory was copied to the new server. Obviously, we had to change the database name, user name and password inside `/sites/default/settings.php`. At a first glance, the front page appeared as it should, so did several other pages. But when I tried to login, I got an unexpected error. The same occurs when I try to run `rebuild.php`. So I checked the `watchdog` database table for a log message and realized that nothing had been written. I assume the reason why the pages get served is because these are cached. Did I miss something here? How exactly can I verify if the database connection is successful and what could be the issue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just check trust host setting.

Comment: Yeah, check trusted host settings. And check if your .htaccess got copied along. And also double-check or diff your Apache/Nginx config and fix any eventual differences.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. We now swapped the databases of the developement and production versions, which works for the moment. We conclude that there must have gone something wrong when we copied the database, otherwise this should not work either. That's a bit mysterious...